# svg feMerge does't works with firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-filters

i have a problem with my SVG on FireFox:

exemple:
http://pilat.free.fr/english/filters/filtre_fme.htm

this SVG works on Chrome but not on FF(v24.0), why?

i need to know how to merge 2 images with crossbrowser solution.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like feImage in FF doesn't like the fact that you are referencing an internal `<image>` rather than an external file.  It looks like IE may have the same restriction.

Also, I'm not sure that instancing the filter with an empty `<use>` element is going to work reliably.  As far as I am aware the spec doesn't specify how to behave when the `use` doesn't reference anything.

One solution would be to use external URLs in your feImage elements and pass each image through an feColorMatrix (to apply the opacity) before combining them with an feMerge.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/p6qJu/

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, feImage is only currently implemented for complete images and not for document fragments. You should pull the images into your filter directly using an feImage referring to the source image URL, not to the ID's of the image tags.

(This is a duplicate of question 17075857)